# ORA-38104: LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-38104

I need to update the rows on `(D.SELLER_ACCOUNT_ID = S.ACCOUNT_ID AND D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_OLD)`.

How is it possible to correct the query below in Oracle?

```
MERGE INTO T_EVM_CLASSIFICATION D
   USING (SELECT CATEGORY_ID_NEW, CATEGORY_ID_OLD, ACCOUNT_ID FROM DATA_TEMP) S
   ON (D.SELLER_ACCOUNT_ID = S.ACCOUNT_ID AND D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_OLD)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_NEW;
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @Rams: The error is right in the title of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is 1:1 relationship use a simple `update`:

```
update t_evm_classification d set category_id = (
  select category_id_new 
    from data_temp s
    where d.seller_account_id = s.account_id 
      and d.category_id = s.category_id_old )
```

The above update will nullify `category_id` if data in temp table is not present. To avoid this add `where` clause:

```
update t_evm_classification d 
  set category_id = ( select category_id_new 
                        from data_temp s
                       where d.seller_account_id = s.account_id 
                         and d.category_id = s.category_id_old )
  where (d.seller_account_id, d.category_id) in 
    (select s.account_id, category_id_old from data_temp s)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! This looks perfect, but throws ORA-01407: cannot update (%s) to NULL.

I checked, and there are no NULLs in `data_temp` table.
I also tried the inner select without the update: 

`select category_id_new 
    from data_temp s, t_evm_classification d
    where d.seller_account_id = s.account_id 
      and d.category_id = s.category_id_old`

, and it returns correct data.

Comment: @KonstantinFedosov - If you have data in the target table that doesn't have a match in the source table, the subquery will return no rows. If the subquery is used as a scalar subquery (as it is here, for assignment in an UPDATE statement), then "no rows" is treated as NULL, so an attempt is made to update `category_id` to `NULL`, for at least one row of the target table. The solution, here as in the original `MERGE` statement (I show in another Answer how to fix that), is to move the check on `category_id_old` to a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @KonstantinFedosov -  Seems that `category_id` cannot be nullable. Good. Second version of my `update`, containing `where` protects us against update in such situation. The only other reason is that `data_temp.category_id_new` contains some null values. Anyway @mathguy's solution should be faster, so use it.

Answer (score 2):

Move the "offending" condition from the ON clause to the WHERE clause:

```
MERGE INTO T_EVM_CLASSIFICATION D
   USING (SELECT CATEGORY_ID_NEW, CATEGORY_ID_OLD, ACCOUNT_ID FROM DATA_TEMP) S
   ON (D.SELLER_ACCOUNT_ID = S.ACCOUNT_ID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET   D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_NEW
                            WHERE D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_OLD;
```

Comment: Regarding that `WHERE` clause, it's worth mentioning that it doesn't seem to profit from any indexes on `BUNDLE_NAME`, so the `UPDATE` statement (or [some other workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009449/521799)) definitely seems preferrable

Comment: @LukasEder - what is `BUNDLE_NAME`? I don't see it anywhere in the `MERGE` statement, so I don't really know what you are talking about. If you do, please explain. In any case: note that there are instances where `MERGE` will work while `UPDATE` will not - for example, if there are no duplicates in column `S.ACCOUNT_ID` but the column is not explicitly constrained to be `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong column name. I had just answered another question before, with `BUNDLE_NAME` as a column. In this case, it would be `CATEGORY_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

[There are a few possible workarounds which can be used to outsmart the parser](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/02/how-to-work-around-ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated/), at least until Oracle 18c. One of them is to wrap your predicate in a row value expression predicate using an additional dummy column:

```
MERGE INTO T_EVM_CLASSIFICATION D
   USING (SELECT CATEGORY_ID_NEW, CATEGORY_ID_OLD, ACCOUNT_ID FROM DATA_TEMP) S
   ON (D.SELLER_ACCOUNT_ID = S.ACCOUNT_ID 
     AND (D.CATEGORY_ID, 'dummy') = ((S.CATEGORY_ID_OLD, 'dummy')))
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.CATEGORY_ID = S.CATEGORY_ID_NEW;
```